# Setting dynamic fields to 'initial' in model

Tags: django

Like how we normally set initial data, because we know what are the fields for that model.

> initial = { 'fieldA' : valueA, 'fieldB' : valueB}

How do we set fields that are not known and dynamic? (i.e. we don't know what are the fields as the fields will be based on database) This is because my fields are dynamic and are not known. 
This is my forms.Form in def **init**:

```
 for f in Parameter.objects.filter(id=idfield):          

            if Part.objects.get(parameter=f.parameter_name).isfunction:
                self.fields.update({
                            f.parameter_name : forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput() )})
```

As you can see, the fields are generated based on idfield.

For example
If we have just 2 records in database, i just want it to appear as:

```
initial = {'a':'a', 'b' : 'b'}
```

If we have 3 records likewise,

```
initial = {'a':'a', 'b' : 'b', 'c' :'c'}
```

I thought of doing a for loop but the colon seems to be the obstacle because it will appear as a string. Can't seem to find a workaround for this.
Appreciate any suggestions thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
f.parameter_name : forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(), initial=u'My cool initial value')
```